# WPF Toolkit Datagrid with checkbox: How to implement and receive the value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

My datagrid is not going to read any value from database, but just need to read a list of text to be the option name. how to implement it in wpf ? i mean i don't know what the xaml for this and code to read the option reply back by the end user. this will be the exact grid view:

```
------------------
checkbox | Black
------------------
checkbox | White
------------------
checkbox | Blue
------------------
checkbox | Green
------------------
checkbox | Grey
------------------
checkbox | Orange
------------------
```

if the user selected and clicked on submit button, i need someway to read user checked value. may i know how could i implement this or is there any better way for this function ? Thank you for reply.

The file after edit with solution:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ColorBox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="ColorBox.backoption"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="backoption"
    Width="977" Height="637" Background="#FF333333" xmlns:WPFtoolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:MyType}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid Margin="43,101,42,48">

                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <CheckBox Checked="{Binding Path=Checked}"/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Permission}"/>
                            </Grid>

                    </Grid>
     </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window>
```

and the code behind the wpf file :

```
namespace ColorBox
{
    public partial class backoption: Window
    {
        public backoption()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
            MyType Beta = new MyType();
            Beta.Checked = false;
            Beta.Permission = "Hello";

        }
    }

    public class MyType
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
        public string Permission { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a list with your data (colors) using DataTemplates.
Your data template will be:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:MyType}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ColorName}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Your class will be:

```
public class MyType // Should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
{
    public bool Selected {get; set;}
    public string ColorName {get;set;}

    //....
}
```

And all the rest is to add your "MyType"s list to ViewModel and bind it as ItemsSource to your items container.

Comment: No problem, just replace Rectangle with TextBox.

Comment: @oxilumin, may i know how to add the value in the list ? while the window get initial ?

Comment: namespace SunX
{
 public partial class background: Window
 {
  public background()
  {
   this.InitializeComponent();
   
   // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
  }
 }

    public class MyType
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }
        public string Permission { get; set; }

        //....
    }
}

Comment: @oxilumin if you do RelativeSource.Self and bind to Checked property for the same checked property you are binding same source property to same destination property. How will it work? Your binding is wrong.

Comment: If you use ObservableCollection - just add them anytime you want, they will appear automatically. If you use ordinary List - you should all them before before view initialization.

Comment: @AkashKava - I'm sorry, my bad. I'll fix it.

Comment: @oxilumin, i think i don't know how to reference this {x:Type my:MyType}, can you please teach me on where to letting it reference the class ? Please.

Comment: @SpencerLim xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespaceContainsMyType" They should be in the <Window ... > tag.

Comment: @oxilumin, this is what i edit >.< and found a lot of problem because i noob @.@

Comment: Checked="{Binding Path=Checked}" is not valid. '{Binding Path=Checked}' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.

Comment: Ok, wait a moment, I'll send you a completed solution.

Comment: @oxilumin, wondering where your color name come from.. i mean, i didn't see you give any value to colornames but it gor value there >.< and how to read the selected value, is it with the function Selected ?

Comment: Color names are created in App.LoadColorNames() method. You can read values from code using MainWindowViewModel object which is created in App.OnStartup(...) method. Just open app.xaml and press F7 (or open app.xaml.cs).

Comment: @oxilumin, because i got no much of experience in wpf.... now only know apps. can make some function to it =D if i want to get user selected value ?

Comment: @SpencerLim For example you can add such code to App.OnStartup method: foreach (var colorItem in viewModel.ColorItems)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(colorItem.ColorName + " " + colorItem.Selected);
            }

Comment: @SpencerLim In right case you should use wpf commands to receive some user actions, I'd like to suggest you read Pro WPF in C# 2010 book about it(http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-2010-Matthew-MacDonald/dp/1430272058) it's really nice stuff.

Comment: Thx =D @oxilumin, this 2 hours you let me learned a lot from you ^^ Just nice XD

Comment: @oxilumin, you're right, it's now time for me to picking up the book again XD